# Regular expression to match a number followed by a symbol repeated that many times?

Tags: regex, grammar

How can I create a RegEx that can match the following:

```
a3bbb
aaaa3bbb
a4bbbb
aaa5bbbbb
```

I.e., `a` (one or more times), then a non-negative number, then `b` repeated 'that many times' (as many as the number between `a` and `b`).

Is this language regular? If not, can we construct a CFG for this?

Edit: As for whether the number is single digit, I would say no. (also as Daniel Centore and rici point out, the language is not even CF. Then the natural question is, is it context-sensitive or unrestricted?)

Comment: What do you mean "is this language regular", and what have you tried?

Comment: Homework? Regexes are more general than regular languages; also, the former are more a practical matter, the latter theoretical.

Comment: But what language are you using?

Comment: Not a homework question. I think I explained it without ambiguity. As for regex vs regular languages, I can take either answer but theoretical is preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like other answers have said, if the number is unbounded, the language is neither regular (if it's regular, pumping lemma says for a sufficiently long string, the `b`'s could be extended indefinitely independent of the number) nor context-free (if it's context-free, pumping lemma says for a sufficiently long number, the number and the `b`'s could be repeated, but not correctly).

But the language is context-sensitive, as it can be generated using the following grammar (I do it for base-3 number for simplicity, you can extend to base 10):

```
(1) S -> aS | aB
(2) B -> BN | N
(3) aN -> a0 | a1b | a2bb
(4) 0N -> 00 | 01b | 02bb
(5) 1N -> 10 | 11b | 12bb
(6) 2N -> 20 | 21b | 22bb
(7) bN -> WN
(8) WN -> WX
(9) WX -> NX
(10)NX -> Nbbb
```

Rule (1) is to generate the `a`'s

Rule (2) is to generate each digit in the number

Rule (3)-(6) is to replace the left-most `N` with a number and respective number of `b`'s.

Rule (7)-(10) is to have the `N` "consume" the `b`'s to its left, and produce 3 `b`'s (10 `b`'s in base-10). Technically (7)-(10) is just `bN -> Nbbb`.

Example:

```
To generate: a102bbbbbbbbbbb (102 in base-3 = 11 in base-10)
S
aB (1b)
aBN (2a)
aBNN (2a)
aNNN (2b)
a1bNN (3b)
a1NbbbN (7)-(10)
a1NbbNbbb (7)-(10)
a1NbNbbbbbb (7)-(10)
a1NNbbbbbbbbb (7)-(10)
a10Nbbbbbbbbb (5a)
a102bbbbbbbbbbb (4c)
```

Comment: Based on my basic familiarity with CS grammars, shouldn't something like rule (3) look like this: aN -> a0 | a1b | a2bb ? because that's what you seem to be doing in the example at (3b). (similarly for other rules).

Answer (score 4):

This language is not regular (and thus cannot be expressed as a RegEx). One test for language regularity is to check if it can be expressed by a Finite Automaton. It can be shown that this language cannot be expressed as an FA because the FA would need at least as many states as the number between `a` and `b`, but that number is not bounded. However, if it is bounded (*ex* the number can only be from 1-10) then it would be Regular.

The language also cannot be expressed as a CFG, which can probably be shown using the pumping lemma.

Comment: I guess I should've asked "is it context-sensitive? or not even that?". Do you mind commenting?

Comment: @FiZixer I think it is context-sensitive, I have provided a grammar for it in my answer.

Comment: You are correct; my apologies. It is context sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

If the number is a single digit, then the language is regular (because you can just list the nine possible suffixes). But if the number is not bounded, the language not regular. It is not even context-free. So neither a regular expression nor a CFG are available.

Comment: Perhaps you should say "If the number is bounded, then the language is regular" instead of "single digit", although it could result in a very huge rules for the language.

Comment: OK. I think that was implicit, but it might as well be explicit.

Comment: I think you can edit your first sentence also, if you prefer. +1